# Applications of unbounded measures outside of mathematics

Tags: measure-theory, applications

Revised based on comments.

Measure-theoretic probability is used in finance (among other fields).

However, was wondering where unbounded measures are used, outside of mathematics and physics. For example, is there a use for unbounded measures in finance or biology or business?

Apologies for a broad question -- there really is not 'right answer' but hoping this group will have suggestions. Many thanks!

Comment: PDE is often used in an applied way, and measure theory is used in geometric measure theory, which is related to PDEs. (See for example Alessio Figalli's book "Partial Differential Equations and Geometric Measure Theory".)

Comment: This is way too broad: Each time one uses, for instance, spaces $L^p$ (say, in analysis), one uses measure theory.

Comment: @moishe kohan — what if we restrict to applications of unbounded measures. Apologies if this is too broad but hopefully you get the gist — that probability is the well known “applied use” of measure theory but I’m curious of that is it and the rest of its uses are only theoretical.

Comment: @Bey This does not really help, since the spaces such as $L^p({\mathbb R})$ are widely used in analysis. I am really unsure how to narrow down your question. Perhaps, you should pick a specific area of math which is not analysis. But even this might not help. (E.g., if you were to ask me about algebraic geometry, I would not know what to say, at least immediately. But, for instance, unbounded measures are widely used in the theory of arithmetic groups. Sard's theorem is a measure-theoretic result widely used in topology.)

Comment: @MoisheKohan so I revised my question to be more specific -- I'm looking for how unbounded measures are used outside of mathematics. My example is how probability measures are used in finance via stochastic processes. As you can tell I'm not super familiar with all this -- I just want to know what examples would be trotted out for unbounded measures like probability is for bounded ones.

Comment: In your edit you simply say "other fields" (after mentioning combinatorics). Please, edit **the body of the question** (not just the title) to make it clear that you are looking for applications in fields other than mathematics. (You should also exclude theoretical physics since measure theory is quire important there as well, in particular in stat physics, quantum mechanics and quantum field theory.)

Comment: @MoisheKohan thanks -- I updated per your suggestion. Thanks for your patience :)

Comment: By "unbounded", do you simply mean sets of infinite measure are allowed? The linear measure of the reals is infinite, the planar measure of the plane is infinite, the linear measure of the graph of $y = x$ is infinite, the planar measure of the exterior of the the graph of $|x| + |y| < 1$ is infinite, for very many (uncountably many . . .) Hausdorff measures the Cantor set (or any uncountable closed set) has infinite measure, etc. Indeed, to me it seems very strange to always restrict oneself to situations in which sets of infinite measure are not allowed.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro -- yes, like I always hear about how measure theory is applied through probability but that works because the bounded measures lend themselves to frequency interpretation or "allocation of belief" -- in unbounded measures it's not clear there is a real-world analog that would benefit. Again, measure theory  newbie question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the basis for Analysis: Existence and uniqueness of the Lebesgue measure ("the standard volume") is proven in Measure theory, the Lebesgue measure is used when integrating (Analysis).

Comment: +1 thanks! I'm looking for applications in other fields -- I clarified based on feedback in the comments.